# How do I use MemoryCache to speedup translation of various objects into strings?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

I have a large dataset (`IEnumerable` of `[Table]`-attributed class objects) from a Linq-To-Sql query and I need to produce a CSV file from it. I loop over the dataset and for each item I convert the value of each property of the item into a string using various formatting options.

```
Type t = typeof(T);
var properties = t.GetProperties();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        // This is made using delegates, but whatever
        object value = property.GetValue(item, null);
        // convert to string and feed to StringBuilder
    }
}
```

The problem is that conversion takes even longer that running the query. The dataset contains heavily denormalized data - numerous items have the same properties having the same values and only some properties having different values. Each property value is translated separately for each item in the dataset. So my code converts the same data into the same strings - over and over. And I'd like to somehow speed this up, preferable without changing the SQL query.

Looks like [`MemoryCache` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could work, but I need to craft unique keys for each object. I can't figure out how I could craft such keys reliably and efficiently enough.

How do I make use of `MemoryCache` so that I can cache translation results for objects of different types?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to speed it up I would suggest ExpressionTrees more than MemoryCache.  This assumes you don't have nested objects to want to read and I can use reflection on the first item and it will be the same for each item in the IEnumerable - which from your example code in the question seems correct.

Also if it's big and you are going to just write it out to a file I would suggest going straight to a FileStream instead of a StringBuilder.

```
public class CSV
{
    public static StringBuilder ToCSV(IEnumerable list)
    {
        Func<object, object[]> toArray = null;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Need to initialize the loop and on the first one grab the properties to setup the columns
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (toArray == null)
            {
                toArray = ItemToArray(item.GetType());
            }
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", toArray(item)));
        }

        return sb;
    }

    private static Func<object, object[]> ItemToArray(Type type)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
        var arrayBody = new List<Expression>();

        // Create a parameter to take the item enumeration
        var sourceObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object), "source");
        // Convert it to the type that is passed in
        var sourceParam = Expression.Convert(sourceObject, type);

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;

            if (IsValueProperty(propType))
            {
                // get the value of the property
                Expression currentProp = Expression.Property(sourceParam, prop);
                // Need to box to an object if value type
                if (propType.IsValueType)
                {
                    currentProp = Expression.TypeAs(currentProp, typeof (object));
                }
                // Add to the collection of expressions so we can build the array off of this collection
                arrayBody.Add(currentProp);
            }
        }
        // Create an array based on the properties
        var arrayExp = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof (object), arrayBody);

        // set a default return value of null if couldn't match
        var defaultValue = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof (object), Expression.Constant(null));

        //Set up so the lambda can have a return value
        var returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof (object[]));
        var returnExpress = Expression.Return(returnTarget, arrayExp, typeof (object[]));
        var returnLabel = Expression.Label(returnTarget, defaultValue);

        //Create the method
        var code = Expression.Block(arrayExp, returnExpress, returnLabel);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[]>>(code, sourceObject).Compile();
    }


    private static bool IsValueProperty(Type propertyType)
    {
        var propType = propertyType;

        if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>))
        {
            propType = new NullableConverter(propType).UnderlyingType;
        }

        return propType.IsValueType || propType == typeof (string);
    }
}
```